# Type-unsafe behavior of Casbah

Tags: mongodb, casbah

I have an `id` which is Long. But if I `getAs[String]`, it blindly returns `Some(0)` instead of None. It checks the presence of the key and not the type.

```
scala> collection
res26: com.mongodb.DBObject = { "_id" : { "$oid" : "520f8bf544ae41ec63d02eec"} , "date_about" : "2013-08-17T20:13:00.365Z" , "date_created" : "2013-08-17T20:13:00.365Z" , "date_modified" : "2013-09-07T18:03:20.101Z" , "id" : 0 , "node_type" : "meta-folder" , "parent_id" : 0 , "title" : "my stuff, renamed by ajax, wow" , "version" : 2}

scala> collection.getAs[String]("id")
res27: Option[String] = Some(0)

scala> collection.getAs[Long]("id")
res28: Option[Long] = Some(0) //get-ing this is an java.lang.ClassCastException

scala> collection.getAs[Long]("id").get
res29: Long = 0
```

Is this not unexpected behavior; should I not have got a `Option[String] = None`? How do i get the expected behavior? I sbt-ed "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.6.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a ticket to Casbahs issue tracker: [SCALA-136](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SCALA-136) and will fix in the Casbah 2.7.0 release.